# C# Databound Listbox Refresh

Tags: c#, databound, listboxitems

I've checked the answers on this topic however I still have no idea why this is not working! PLEASE HELP!

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCeCommand insTitle = new SqlCeCommand("Insert into Titles(Title) values('" + txtAddTitle.Text +"')");
        insTitle.Connection = dbConnection;

        try 
        {
            if (dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { dbConnection.Open(); }
            insTitle.ExecuteNonQuery();


            this.hRDataSet.AcceptChanges();
            this.titlesTableAdapter.Update(this.hRDataSet);
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.hRDataSet);

            lstTitles.BeginUpdate();
            lstTitles.DataSource = titlesBindingSource;
            lstTitles.DisplayMember = "Title";
            lstTitles.ValueMember = "Title_ID";
            lstTitles.EndUpdate();
        }
        catch (Exception insErr)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(insErr.Message);
        }
    }
```

The listbox "lstTitles" won't refresh and doesn't show the added items despite the fact that they are in the database!

Comment: Do you really understand the code you wrote? This looks suspiciously like [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)...

Comment: I've tried so many different ways of coding ... it is all gibraish to me now. Can you help after the "executenonquery" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Update` method of the `DataAdapter` is used to update the database with the changes made in the `DataSet`. What you need to do here is the opposite: you need to update the `DataSet` with the modified data from the database, so you should use `Fill`, not `Update`.

Anyway, your approach is not optimal; since you're working with datasets, you should add the new value to the appropriate table in the `DataSet`, and then update the database with the `Update` method. The ListBox will automatically pick up the changes.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try 
    {
        // Add a row to the DataTable
        DataRow row = hRDataSet.Titles.NewRow();
        row["Title"] = txtAddTitle.Text;
        hRDataSet.Titles.Rows.Add(row);

        // Update the database
        this.titlesTableAdapter.Update(this.hRDataSet);

        // That's it, you're done ;)
    }
    catch (Exception insErr)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(insErr.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that... the only reason I went down this road is because my .sdf is not being updated with new records if I update the dataset first... at least not when I click on "show table data" under server explorer!

Comment: and that is because I was running it in debug mode! DUHHH!

Comment: @user799920, just change the "Copy to output directory" property of your sdf file